# Alphabetically sort the rows of a 2d array containing only one column of values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```php
$name = [
    ['Jane Smith'],
    ['John Paul'],
    ['Jennifer'],
    ['Paolo'],
    ['Delilah'],
];
```

Is it possible to alphabetically arrange this array?
How can I use the `sort()` in here?

Comment: So you're trying to sort an array of arrays of strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array  = your array

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
sort($result);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php

$ar1 = array("Jane Smith", "John Paul ", "Jennifer", "Paolo","Delilah");
function alphasort($a, $b) {
    if ($a['name'] == $b['name']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort ($ar1,'alphasort');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ar1);

?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Delilah
    [1] => Jane Smith
    [2] => Jennifer
    [3] => John Paul 
    [4] => Paolo
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$array  = your array;
asort($array);
```

Try this [**LINK**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're trying to sort an array of arrays of strings instead of an array of strings, you cannot use `sort()`.

```
$array = array(array('Jane Smith'), array('John Paul'), array('Jennifer'));

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $a = $a[0];
    $b = $b[0];
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");

foreach($name as $a){
    print_r($a);
}
```

Example code based on [this documentation](http://php.net/usort).

Comment: should I store the `usort($array, "cmp");` in a variable? then print it?

Comment: No, `usort()` modifies the actual array.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) for all kinds of PHP array sorting. But for your specific question after doing `array_merge()` on all you arrays to have a single onw, either `sort()` or `asort()` should work just like this:

```
$all=array();
foreach($name as $a){
    $all=array_merge($all, $a);
}
sort($all);
print_r($all);
```

OR

```
$all=array();
foreach($name as $a){
    $all=array_merge($all, $a);
}
asort($a);
print_r($a);
```